# Mobclix ADs inside Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobclix

I have lost much time solving this problem, and looks like I'm back at the beginning.
I want to run the full screen ADs from the Mobclix inside my Unity3D game. I found many tutorials but I can't get any of them working.

As far as I know, there are 2 approaches:
1.) extending unity player
2.) make JAVA side method for showing the AD's and just call it from the unity(c#)

Most important for me is to make it work, but I would prefer 2. approach.
Can somebody suggest me something and maybe give some hints/examples what am I missing?

I tried both ways. I made an JAVA plugin but when I try to call a method nothing happens or I got an error from JNI something like: "can't find that method", my manifest is not configured correctly, or my app crashes.

If I'm making a plugin (not extending UnityPlayer) do I need to add something to the manifest to support my activity/make my class able to call inside unity? How would the manifest look like? Can it be done that way?

If I'm extending the UnityPlayer how would mthe anifest file looks like and how can I call my method for that will show ADs?

I tried to call java/android methods from the unity/c# and that worked, but when I try to call my own simple method from the plugin it won't work. Looks like I'm missing something in that part. (connecting the JAVA plugin and the unity3d)

I'm experienced in the C#, but my JAVA knowledge is really at the minimum. I'm sure this can work (there are people that are selling solutions) but looks like I'm not smart enough and keep missing something :)

I tried many things, I stopped counting and deleted most of them. Can somebody tell me the right way to do this? A working example would be really useful...

Thanks for taking the time to read all of this, I hope there will be some useful responses because I'm starting to get depressed :)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it looks like the absolute easiest way is to purchase a plugin, made just for this. I found one [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=sLKBplWPL-v1JG7pRJyRL22ygqS4o9P0l9MzAuDlAP6AnqTNyKNLU_D6H4a&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198c76d66ace6699a60677529753b095fab), which costs $50, and it specifically stated it supports fullscreen Mobclix ads.

There is a free one developed by the staff at Unity3D forums, however,  it seems more complex, in that you must run it on the actual android device, and I am not sure if it supports full screen. You can find the discussion thread [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/78453-Mobclix-plugin-that-works-with-Unity-3.2).

Hope these links helped!

**Edit**: I found a much more affordable £6.00 Unity3D plugin, which  you can get [here](http://www.platoevolved.com/blog/unity-plugins/#ecwid%3acategory=2743024&mode=product&product=11950435). It did not explicitly state support for fullscreen, however.

**Note**: I found a [tutorial](http://www.platoevolved.com/blog/programming/android/creating-an-android-plugin-for-unity/) from the very same website that offers the £6 plugin. This tutorial might be worth checking into, however it involves compiling your own Unity Android plugin. Because it is from the same website, it may be worth checking into. It is specifically a plugin to display Mobclix ads on a Unity3D for Android app.

Comment: tnx on response... I thought none will reply :)
I tried that one from unity3d forums, but didn't make it work. Hopefully I will have more luck tomorrow. 

I'm indie developer and don't have much in my budget, so I want to make it by myself.  :)

Comment: Like I said, you have to try on the actual device, I think. Also, [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/78453-Mobclix-plugin-that-works-with-Unity-3.2?p=506048&viewfull=1#post506048) post and [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/78453-Mobclix-plugin-that-works-with-Unity-3.2?p=507991&viewfull=1#post507991) post explain some extra steps you might want to try. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you... I tried them with no luck but will go from scratch again today.
From logic of that code looks like extending player like that would display ads on every unity stage, but if that will work, maybe I will find a way to modify it to my needs.